# How to fill a form thats inside an Iframe with python

Tags: python, internet-explorer, iframe

So Im trying to login to a site automatically using this python script.

```
from win32com.client import Dispatch
import win32com.client
import time,ids

IE=Dispatch("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Visible=1
IE.Navigate("Source.html")
while IE.ReadyState != 4:    # Wait for browser to finish loading.
    time.sleep(1)
doc = IE.Document # Get the document.
while doc.readyState != "complete": # Wait for document to finish
    time.sleep(1)
doc.Login.USER.value = ids.username    
doc.Login.PASSWORD.value = ids.password
doc.Login.submit() 
while IE.ReadyState != 4:    # Wait for browser to finish loading.
    time.sleep(1)
doc = IE.Document # Get the document.
while doc.readyState != "complete": # Wait for document to finish
    time.sleep(1)
time.sleep(30)
IE.Application.Quit();
```

It works fine on normal sites, but Source.html loads a site in an Iframe.
So the username and password fields are inside an Iframe and I have no idea how to enter data into those.

Comment: try selenium http://seleniumhq.org/

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try access the element, the iframe, through its id.

Something a long the lines of,
the page/doc your loading have the following element in it,

`<iframe id='myframe'>`

From your code try something like this,
doc.myframe.Login.user

One thing you could do is to open up python REPL and play around with your doc object to figure out how to access the element your looking for.